# Getting error on Algolia search when implementing in my app

Tags: meteor, algolia

I'm getting error when implementing in my app.
Here is my error console:

```
filters: Unexpected token \'(\' expected \')\' at col 81' }
```

I'm new to Algolia. Can anyone help to shot out my error?
Here is my content in algolia displaying:

```
objectID:asdfasfwersa1as54asdf
_id: "asdfasfwersa1as54asdf"
status: "OK"
appId: "app_4s54f"
nameId: "abc_test_(test_app)"
name: "abc test(test app)"
```

Here is my query:

```
    FilterSearch= {
    filterQuery: function (customQuery, type) {
        var filters = "";
        if (type == "Website") {
            filters = "status:OK";
        }
        else if (!_.isEmpty(customQuery.nameId)) {
            if (filters != "")filters += " AND ";
            filters += "(nameId:" + customQuery.nameId.join(" OR nameId:") + ")";
        }
        return {filters: filters, searchKeyword: customQuery.searchKeyword};
    }
};

var searchCriteria=FilterSearch.filterQuery(condition,type);
index.search(searchCriteria.searchKeyword,{facets:facetName,filters:searchCriteria.filters},,Meteor.bindEnvironment(function searchDone(err, content) {
    console.log(searchCriteria.filters);
    if(err) {
        console.error('Algolia returned an error', err);
        future.return(err);
    }
    else {
        if(content.facets[facetName] != undefined) {
            Names.find({$and: [{_id: {$in: _.keys(content.facets[facetName])}}]})
        }

    }
}));
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the query you're doing? It looks like you're passing a wrongly formatted `filters` query parameter.

Comment: @redox i have updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you'll need to use quotes around your `nameId` values because they contain characters the [`filters`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/ruby/parameters#filters) parser isn't able able to handle as being part of a value.

```
filters += "(nameId:\"" + customQuery.nameId.join("\" OR nameId:\"") + "\")";
```

You'll also need to escape double quotes if your `nameId` field can contain some.